# Select from dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a query in sql that depending on the month and year I need to call a different table.

For example:

If current_date is 31/08/2020, execute:
select * from table_ago

If current_date is 01/09/2020, execute:
select * from table_sep

Is it posible using a query in SQL Server?

Comment: Fix your schema and this problem simply goes away. And notice that you refer to month and year yet your code does nothing different if current date is in 2020 or in 2021 (or any other year). Will this become a problem for "someone else"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stored procedure and if condition to make possible such a thing like following

```
create procedure spCheckTable
@date date   --create variable to enter date as parameter
as begin
    declare @toBeCheckDate date = (select top 1 date_column from BaseTable) --create variable to store date from table
    if @toBeCheckDate = @date
        begin
            select * from table_ago
        end
    else if @toBeCheckDate = @date
        begin
            select * from table_sep
        end
end
```

Now run the procedure like follow

```
execute spCheckTable '2020-09-02'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible in a non-dynamic query if the two tables have the sample columns.  If so, you can use `union all`:

```
select *
from table_ago
where convert(date, getdate()) = '2020-08-31'
union all
select *
from table_sep
where convert(date, getdate()) = '2020-09-01';
```

If the tables have different columns, then you probably need to use a stored procedure . . . but it would be hard to use the results in a query.

Comment: In my case I have 60 tables ... one for each month/year, is there a better solution than union? I didn't want to call the database 60 times.

Comment: @FelipeFB . . . Construct the query in your application to just use the correct table.  Then fix your data model so you only have one table with a separate date column.